# Proof of Fredholm Alternative Theorem (linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Question:**

Let $A \in M_{m \times n}(\Bbb R)$, $x \in \Bbb R^n$ and $b,y \in \Bbb R^m$.

Suppose $b$ is such that $b^Ty = 0$ whenever $A^Ty=0$. Show that there exists $x$ such that $Ax = b$.

---

**Attempt:**

I didn't get very far. I managed to show that $Ax = b \iff \text{rank}(A) = \text{rank}(A|b)$ where $A|b$ is an augmented matrix.

Any help would be much appreciated.

A reference to a website containing a proof is also more than welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N(A)$ and $R(A)$ be the null space and column space of a matrix $A$.

The assumption on $b$ implies $b\in N(A^T)^\perp$. The claim is $b\in R(A)$. It remains to show $R(A)=N(A^T)^\perp$.

First, $R(A)^\perp = N(A^T)$. If $y\in R(A)^\perp$ then $y^TAx=0$ for all $x$, which implies $A^Ty=0$. Conversely $A^Ty=0$ implies  $y^TAx=0$ for all $x$, hence $y\in R(A)^\perp$.

The double-orthogonal complement $R(A)^{\perp\perp}$ is $R(A)$, since $R(A)$ is a linear subspace of some finite-dimensional inner product space.

Then we can conclude
$$
R(A) = R(A)^{\perp\perp} = N(A^T)^\perp,
$$
which is the claim.